# ng-hide not working on option elements on iOS devices

Tags: angularjs

I am building a date selector for a user to input their age. It is three dropdowns (year, month, day) and I have been using `ng-hide` to prevent the user from inputting invalid dates (February 30) or dates that mean the user is under 18 years of age.

***Example***: If the user selects 1997, then the months from June to December are hidden and also the dates from tomorrow to the end of the month are hidden - thus making it impossible for a user to input a date that would mean they are under age.

It all works fine on desktop and android devices, however, when testing it on my iPhone I have found that the options in the dropdowns are not hidden under any circumstances. I have provided a fiddle below to illustrate my point. The question is... is this a well known issue with iOS devices or am I forgetting something?

http://jsfiddle.net/adamjld/oousahsg/1/

Comment: Try removing the curly brackets in this part: `ng-hide="year==over18Year && {{$index + 1}}`

Comment: Doesn't seem to have made any difference I'm afraid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`. Not really sure CSS display attribute is '*really*' supported for option elements, and it's that `ng-show` is based on. Seems not to be the case on iOS anyway.

Anyway, the correct approach would be to use `ng-options` on your selects and recompute the list of options dynamically when user change other fields.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. iOS doesn't play well with the display attribute on select options. Changed this around to use ng-options and custom filters and seems to be working across all devices now :)